# Detect each tab layout in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

What method do I use to detect the current tab that I am in so that I can set the corresponding method and action for this tab?

Answer (score 1):

On your TabHost, use [getCurrentTab()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html#getCurrentTab%28%29) and the methods that follow in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

view  [hello-tabwidget.html](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html) that will give you a great example

```
 mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
```

is used to set any tab to current tab 
and

```
if(tabHost.getCurrentTab() == 0){
            do some thing when current tab is 0
        }
```

the above method will be helpful you..you also may refere this [TabHost](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html#getCurrentTab%28%29)

still getting problem let me know.. thanks Pragna

Comment: Hi, thanks, but that's not what I want, I ment how can I detect each different tab content? because I want set different option menu on different tab content, thanks!

Comment: @Override public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)          {       super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu); if(tabHost.getCurrentTab() == 0) { menu.add(0, MENU_ITEM_INSERT, 0, R.string.menu_insert).setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_add); } return true; } This is my code, I only add option menu on first tab which is still not wworking, please help, thanks!